# Run Configuration Error: Custom RSpec runner script doesn't exist

Tags: ruby, rspec, intellij-idea

I've got an rspec test inside of IntelliJ (NOT RUBYMINE) that I'd like to run through the IDE runner. When I try to run it I get

```
Run Configuration Error: CAnnot find RSpec runner script for ruby-1.9.3-p327 SDK
```

I can't find any information online as to what an "RSpec runner script is", or how I might mock up my own. I was hoping I could find a default implementation and then just point IntelliJ's "use a custom script" to that to circumvent the problem.

Any help finding a runner script, or telling me where I can find information on the runner script would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try opening the corresponding run/debug configuration and select a Ruby SDK for the configuration:

[image: Run/Debug configuration screenshot]

This solved the problem in my case.